# Pipeline for a java based web app on azure devops.Apache maven to create build . Below yaml code and the output error i'm getting

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'smart-test-admin-api/pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
```

BUILD ERROR:
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Malformed POM /home/vsts/work/1/s/smart-test-admin-api/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'repositories' (position: START_TAG seen ...\n    ... @17:19)  @ /home/vsts/work/1/s/smart-test-admin-api/pom.xml, line 17, column 19
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

Comment: If the error message says that there's a malformed tag in pom.xml, guess what file we'd need to provide some help ;)

Comment: so are you saying that the error is in the pom.xml file?

Comment: To quote from your question: "Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR] Malformed POM (...): Unrecognised tag: 'repositories'"

Comment: It seems that this issue is related with the repositories field format. You could refer to the answer and check your pom.xml file. If it still has this issue, you could share a sample of your pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

> Malformed POM /home/vsts/work/1/s/smart-test-admin-api/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'repositories' (position: START_TAG seen ...\n ... @17:19)

Based on the error message, this issue is from the Pom.xml. The format of the **repositories field** in Pom.xml file has some issue.

Here is the correct format sample: you could refer to it and check your content format of the Pom.xml file.

```
<project>
...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo1</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo2</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
...
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response .I'll try making changes in my pom.xml file.